# PHP / MySQL Query merge 2 queries

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if there is an easier way to execute this logic in 1 query rather than using 2 queries and having to loop the second query within the first one.

Firstly I grab the all the users which have been referred by the current `user_id`.

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE referral = $user_id
```

Then, I want to count the number of page hits (or whatever else I'm counting), for each of the user's referrals.

```
SELECT COUNT(hits) FROM tracking WHERE user = $user_id
```

Is there an easier way of doing this with a join?

Comment: is `$user_id` the same for both queries? what's the difference between `$user_id` the php variable and `user_id` the MySQL column?

Comment: user_id in the first query is my user id, for example 100. The user_id in the second query is the user id of everyone I have referred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a [`left join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [`group by`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
select u.user_id, count(t.hits) as hits 
from users u left join tracking t on u.user_id = t.user 
where u.referral = $user_id 
group by u.user_id;
```